# module not found error after qgis installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, qgis

I am new to qgis. I want to install qgis library on anaconda and not qgis desktop software. I am following the link https://plugins.qgis.org/planet/tag/conda/

It was taking so much time for anaconda. It is showing "solving environment" for hours, and somehow I ended up installing qgis.
Now if I write

```
from qgis.core import *
```

It throws an error, module not found. Can you please tell if I am missing any environment variable to be added any where.

Also tell me how do overcome " solving environment" issue in anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

Try this! First of all create a virtualenv (instead conda I used venv, but it the same.

```
python -m venv env
```

Then, you have to activate the virtual env.
On linux you can to this by typing:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

While on windows you can write:

```
env/Scripts/activate
```

Finally install qgis dependency

```
python -m pip install qgis
```

In this way you should be able to run your code:

```
from qgis.core import *
```